# Crashlytics not working when using ANR Watch Dog

Tags: android

In my current project I am using line to initliaze crashlytics :-

```
Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
```

After I came to know about anrWatchDog , I read article https://github.com/SalomonBrys/ANR-WatchDog#can-it-work-with-crash-reporters and tried to integrate and

used code :=

```
new ANRWatchDog().start();

Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
```

But After this addition of code , my `crashlytics` stop sending any `fatal/non-fatal` issues.

Kindly help me what I am missing ?

Answer (score 2):

I have got the solution. I need to use below code to start Anr watch dog.

```
new ANRWatchDog().setReportMainThreadOnly().start();
```